# Bash Functions - Create a variable with parameter's label

Tags: bash, variables, parameters

I'm trying to create a function which will create a variable with the tag $1 (first param) and with the value $3 (third param).

Here is my code:

```
function var
{
    if [ "$2" = "=" ]; then
        $1 = $3
    fi
}
```

Now, I believe the reason this doesn't work is because the way I wrote this function makes bash try to overwrite the value of $1 with that of $3.

Is there a work-around for this?

This is what I'm aiming to do:

```
var i = 1
var greeting = "hello"
```

and both of these variables would be assigned their value.

Comment: What's wrong with `i=1; greeting="hello"`? I'm not sure I understand in what context such a function would be useful.

Comment: @chepner I'm just re-interfacing the bash syntax... It's not meant as anything useful, just fun. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `eval`, use [`declare`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-declare) with the `-g` flag (create global variables)

```
function var {
    if [ "$2" = "=" ]; then
        declare -g "$1=$3"
    fi
}
var foo = bar
echo $foo
```

```
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a portable solution,
just use `eval`:

```
eval "$1=$3"
```

That is it.

Example:

```
 $ function var
 {
   if [ "$2" = "=" ]; then
     eval "$1=$3"
   fi
 }
 $ var a = 10
 $ echo $a
 10
```

If your script is for bash 4+, you can use `declare` with `-g` key (thanks to `glenn jackman`), that declares a varible globally, not only in the function scope:

```
 $ function var
 {
   if [ "$2" = "=" ]; then
     declare -g "$1=$3"
   fi
 }
 $ var a = 10
 $ echo $a
```

In this case you can be sure, that there could be nothing in `"$@"` that can affect something besides `$$1` variable.

Comment: This is going to result in `var: command not found`. And there are better ways than eval anyway.

Comment: @Kevin: No, Kevin, there are no better ways! There were a typo (space) before =, that is because you've gotten the error.

Comment: @Kevin: So, Kevin, please remove your -1. You are obviously not right.

Comment: @Kevin I'm curious as to the better way to set an indirectly named shell variable. I'm pretty certain that portable `sh` only supported `eval` for this purpose.

Comment: I was thinking `declare`, but that evidently doesn't work in a function. And `let` does, but only numeric arguments.

Comment: @Kevin: `declare -g` works, but that is a bashism. Yes, we have `bash`-tag here, but anyway, it's a bashism.

Comment: bash 4+. And you should at least mention it. Less portable, perhaps, but safer when it's available.

Comment: @IgorChubin You are misusing the word "bashism" - it is a derogatory term for using bash features in scripts intended as portable `sh` scripts. There are no "bashisms" in a Bash script, the whole script is a bashism by definition.

Comment: Actually, `export "$1=$2"` seems to work in both bash and sh.

Comment: @Kevin Using `export` has the side effect of exporting the variable (making it visible to forked subprocesses), which may not be desirable.

Comment: @user4815162342: That's write I've written that the script is for `bash`; in other cases this feature is a bashism..

Comment: @Kevin: No, that is wrong; `export` is not just `declare`. You make an environment variable, not just a shell variable.